# Coppier Machine Konica Minolta

Tags: scanning

Everything is working fine on printing but when I try to scan over the network is shows me **Server Connection error**. I tried different way to solve the problem but it does't work.

PC is having static IP and i am trying to connect it through wireless connection
Is there anyone who help me.**your text**

I tried through updating drivers and Try SMB and sharing the folder etc..